# Relational or full object in MongoDB documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a general MongoDB question as I have recently found an issue with how I store things.

Currently, there is a collection called spaces like this:

```
 {
    _id: 5e1c4689429a8a0decf16f69,
    challengers: [
      5dfa24dce9cbc0180fb60226,
      5dfa26f46719311869ac1756,
      5dfa270c6719311869ac1757
    ],
    tasks: [],
    owner: 5dfa24dce9cbc0180fb60226,
    name: 'testSpace',
    description: 'testSpace'
  }
```

As you can see, this has a `challengers` array, in which we store the `ID` of the `User`.

Would it be okey, if instead of storing the ID, I would store the entire User object, minus fields such as password etc?

Or should I continue with this reference path of referring to the ID of other documents?

The problem I have with this, is that when I want to go through all the `spaces` that a user has, I want to see what members are a part of that space (challengers array). However, I receive the IDS instead of name and email obviously. I am therefore struggling with sending the correct data to the frontend (I have tried doing some manual manipulation without luck).

So, if I have to continue the path of reference, then I will need to solve my problem somehow.

If it is okey to store the entire object in the array, It would be a lot easier.

HOWEVER, I want to do what is the best practice.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: It depends on specific requirements. Embedding documents will detach data from original object. If user changes he's  data, you will have still old data in challengers. This might be both feature - immutable document, with state exact as when created. Or problem - having stale data in challengers.

Comment: Yeah good point. I think it is good that I have the IDS as relations then, considering the user can change their name and other information etc

Comment: You could also store *some* user data and ID's, so that you will be able to easy fetch list of users for displaying purposes, ie for some non-critical operations.You can also update all embedded user data after updating user - solution which complicates updating, but makes retrieving data easier.

Comment: Keep references and use aggregation with [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) stage to load required user's data in a single request.

Comment: So if I have the IDS in a document, I can populate the field with the Real referenced Object by using $lookup?

For example, after request, instead of the space document having IDS in the array, it will then have the user objects? @AlexBlex

Comment: Yep, it's like JOIN in SQL